# Why wasn't my flag declined?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently flagged this question: [Check what thread a method is being called from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290733/check-what-thread-a-method-is-being-called-from)

as a duplicate of this one: [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

However, I was reading much too quickly and misunderstood what the OP was asking. In fact, the questions are completely unrelated to each other. However, my flag was marked as "helpful" a short while afterwards.

Why did this happen, when I was clearly mistaken to flag the question as a duplicate? I definitely don't want the question to be closed as dupe when it is actually not. What exactly is happening on the other end, and why might a duplicate flag be incorrectly approved?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: 3 people have voted to close as a duplicate, but [How to check if running on UI thread in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845678/how-to-check-if-running-on-ui-thread-in-android) instead (just stating, not answering this question)

Comment: @gnat Don't see how that's related. I'm not the OP.

Comment: Ironically, I think gnat read the post too quickly and "suggested" a bad duplicate.

Comment: I know. What stops you from editing or at least adding a comment explaining the difference so that other readers won't repeat your mistake? (@gunr2171 it's cross-site, no way to dupe close)

Comment: @gnat I did do exactly that. I even answered the question. But my question here is not about what I should do about this, rather why the flag was deemed "helpful" in the first place.

Comment: I see, then more appropriate cross site dupe is [Bandwagon effect in close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773) "I have proof.

There's a bandwagon effect going on: people are agreeing with existing close votes without thoroughly evaluating whether they're accurate..."

Comment: So the moral of the story is: please at least read the post before you vote or flag.

Comment: @gnat No they're not.  They didn't close it for the reason flagged, they closed it for a different reason (well, a duplicate of a different post, which is the same idea).  They very clearly *weren't* just bandwagoning on the proposed (and incorrect) close reason.

Comment: @Servy Beat me to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone voted to close the question as a duplicate of a different question after you flagged the question.  The additional vote to close automatically marked the flag as helpful, despite the fact that the user didn't close the question as a duplicate of the same post.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if that should be considered a feature or a bug.

Comment: I'm curious. It is only one VTC needed, or multiple? Also I'm sure this is a feature.

Comment: @gunr2171 Just one.